# how to load custom classes using slim middleware in slim framework from a folder to routes

Tags: php, slim-3

below is my example routes i have a custom class called Category but am getting error like this  `Class 'app\Category' not found`

```
 $app->get('/category',function($request, $response, $args){
        $categories = new app\Category();
        $categories->getCategories();

    });
```

how to load this class in order to make use of it in slim framework V3

Comment: this class is in namespace app

Comment: Can you show the whole file or at least the top, where you have namespace declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it loaded through composer autoloader by adding autoload block in composer.json